# Does broadcasting to a ASP.NET SignalR group that is empty waste resources?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

If I have many client connections that are part of my Hub `Hub_X`, but not currently part of a specific group `Group_Y`, is it bad practice to `broadcast()` to `Group_Y`? Should I keep track of whether or not anyone is inside my `Group_Y`, and check accordingly before just broadcasting to it?

Or does `signalR` essentially do no work when it detects there is no one in the `Group_Y`, and therefore use a negligible amount of resources (compared to say, having to track who's in a group myself). ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Broadcasting to empty groups like you describe does have some overhead, but it is probably negligible depending on your use case.

Let's say you have 100,000 messages to process in a queue. Processing any of those messages may require you to send a SignalR message to clients that are watching that data, but the vast majority of messages will have no watchers.

You could use the message/entity ID as the name of the group and execute code like this for every one of the 100,000 messages:

```
var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(hubName);
var group = hub.Clients.Group(groupName) as GroupProxy;
if (group != null)
{
    group.Invoke(actionName, messageData);
}
```

Alternatively, if you were somehow able to manage a `HashSet` of groups that actually have clients (or are likely to have clients) then you could modify your code like so:

```
var activeGroups = new HashSet<string>();
...
if (activeGroups.Contains(groupName))
{
    var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(hubName);
    var group = hub.Clients.Group(groupName) as GroupProxy;
    if (group != null)
    {
        group.Invoke(actionName, messageData);
    }
}
```

This second example seems like overkill and introduces the complexity of managing `activeGroups` (which can probably be done within a custom subclass of `Hub`). Furthermore, I would have expected that internally SignalR is already doing something exactly like this. However, when I benchmark this with 100,000 messages and zero clients (ie: every group is empty) I get 2.5 seconds on the first example and 0.006 seconds on the second example. Whatever SignalR is doing internally to handle empty groups it is certainly less efficient than a `HashSet` lookup.

Running the first test (the slow one) in the Visual Studio performance profiler confirms that most of the work is within internal SignalR functions that are unexpectedly slow compared to a `HashSet`:

[image: Profiler results]